# REGEX blocking ability to Copy, Paste and save data in the field

Tags: validation-rule

Field: Comments__c
Type: Long Text Area
Lines: 3
Number: 1000

With the Regex Formula that I have, I am running into an issue of copying/pasting and saving text in the field (Comment__c).

Formula:

```
AND( 
NOT( ISBLANK(Comment__c)), 
NOT( REGEX(Comment__c, "(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*"))))
```

Has anyone ran across this before?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: It's my Validation Rule Error stating that "Comments need to be entered".

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this using the formula you have (Note that the formula posted here has a syntax error, theres an extra `)`).  Likely it is not the regex, but something in what you're copy-pasting.

Comment: I am simply copying and pasting text

Comment: Can it be the ISBLANK?  I am trying to copy and paste simple text...and the error is thrown.

Comment: @battery.cord I believe that the regex is not allowing copy and pastes with a "hard enter".

Comment: What is the string you are trying to paste?

Comment: Like I said before there is no need for this validation rule. SF will automatically remove all leading and trailing whitespace for you which is what you said you wanted to prevent

Answer (score 3):

While I disagree that you even need this REGEX to check for leading and trailing spaces (according to your previous posts) as salesforce removes them....

The current version of regex will fail on new line.

Change to the to include newLines as well:

```
AND( 
NOT( ISBLANK(Comment__c)),
NOT(REGEX(Comment__c, "(?s)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*"))
)
```

Note the addition of (?s) at the beginning.

Results Before:

1. `111 111` - FAIL
2. `aaa bbb <b> ! .` - Pass
3. `abcd <b> 1234` - PASS
4. `abcd <b> {line break here}
   1234` - FAIL
5. - FAIL

Results After:

1. `111 111` - FAIL
2. `aaa bbb <b> ! .` - Pass
3. `abcd <b> 1234` - PASS
4. `abcd <b> {line break here}
   1234` - **PASS**
5. - FAIL

Explanation of the `(?s)`

[Specifying Modes Inside The Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)

> for "single line mode" makes the dot match all characters, including line breaks